# how to mock the rxjs pipes

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I want to test my code below, but I'm not sure how to test the map and pipe (from RXJS) functions.

I have a method like this in my service file. I am not able to cover the inner method. Please help me in mocking the inner data,

```
 getCurrentUser() {
  return {
  id: '',
  name: '',
 }

 getId(type) {
    return this.getCurrentUser().pipe(map((user) => this.getUser(user, type)));
 }

 getUser(user, type) {
    return 'asdas'; 
 }

spec.ts:

 it('should call getId', () => {
    service.getId(type);
    expect(userServiceSpy.getCurrentUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

Comment: You need to show 2 files. `.ts` and `.spec.ts`.  This is lack detail to solve your issue @Ramya

Comment: Please help me in writing test case for getId(). Im not able to mock the map method.